# How to parse nested JSON object using the json library?

Tags: android, json

i want to parse the json object using json library.

```
    {
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [JSON](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)..

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(yourString);
JSONObject batters = object.getJSONObject("batters");
JSONArray batter = batters.getJSONArray("batter");
for(int i = 0 ; i < batter.length() ; i++) { 
JSONObject object1 = (JSONObject) batter.get(i);
    String id = object1.getString("id");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
"result": "success",
"countryCodeList":
[
  {"countryCode":"00","countryName":"World Wide"},
  {"countryCode":"kr","countryName":"Korea"}
] 
}
```

Here below I am fetching country details

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONArray nameArray = json.names();
JSONArray valArray = json.toJSONArray(nameArray);

JSONArray valArray1 = valArray.getJSONArray(1);

valArray1.toString().replace("[", "");
valArray1.toString().replace("]", "");

int len = valArray1.length();

for (int i = 0; i < valArray1.length(); i++) {

 Country country = new Country();
 JSONObject arr = valArray1.getJSONObject(i);
 country.setCountryCode(arr.getString("countryCode"));                        
 country.setCountryName(arr.getString("countryName"));
 arrCountries.add(country);
}
```