# How to parse the JSON objects with each different key and value, using Java?

Tags: java, json

I know the answer for parsing the JSON of this type:

```
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food"}
```

where there is key value pair, with key being same(like 'id' here) and value differing, and we use a for loop to parse it quickly.

(For those who'd like to see how to parse above JSON, please go to this link: [How to parse nested JSON object using the json library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522562/how-to-parse-nested-json-object-using-the-json-library))

However, the JSON I'm trying to parse is a different one which doesn't have a same key like 'Id' as above for every different value, but every key is a new key with a different value. Below is the example:

```
{
  "disclaimer": "Exchange rates are ...........blah blah",
  "license": "Data sourced from various .......blah blah",
  "timestamp": 1446886811,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.67266,
    "AFN": 65.059999,
    "ALL": 127.896
.
.
All the currency values.
.
   }
}
```

I'm not sure how to parse the above one with all different keys of currencies (currency like AED and their value) and pop them up in a drop down list.

Do I have to write a new line of code for each different currency and value pair or it is in some way possible to use a for loop for this one as well.

Can someone provide some lines code if possible?

Answer (score 2):

you can use org.json for this thing.

E.g.:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("<jsonString>");
 Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + json.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the help and time! If you don't mind, could you please also mention how to pop up the parsed results into a drop down list on Android. This will help the other visitors of this page and me as well. My question is answered and it helped, I tried to vote 1 up, but as I don't have a '15' reputation(new here), it's not getting counted.

Comment: Please look into this for more help :
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-populating-spinner-json-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You could use GSON in this case. I will just print the currencies with the according rate but you can build a different data structure(a map for example) and use it in your system.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "  \"disclaimer\": \"Exchange rates are ...........blah blah\",\n" +
                "  \"license\": \"Data sourced from various .......blah blah\",\n" +
                "  \"timestamp\": 1446886811,\n" +
                "  \"base\": \"USD\",\n" +
                "  \"rates\": {\n" +
                "    \"AED\": 3.67266,\n" +
                "    \"AFN\": 65.059999,\n" +
                "    \"ALL\": 127.896\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> currency: jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("rates").entrySet()){
            System.out.println("Currency "+ currency.getKey()+" has rate " + currency.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time, I tried to vote 1 up for your  answer, but as I don't have 15 reputation, it's not getting counted.  :(