# String to JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse a Json result from a url (the Philips Hue emulator in this case) into a JsonArray in Android Studio. I have the following code so far:

```
String jsonString = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(BASE_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
JSONArray lights;

if (jsonString != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            lights = jsonObject.getJSONArray("lights");

            for (int i = 0; i < lights.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject l = lights.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = l.getString("name");
                String bri = l.getString("bri");
                String hue = l.getString("hue");
                String sat = l.getString("sat");
                String status = l.getString("on");
            }
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Cannot get data from the url");
    }
```

But, when I try to run this code I get a (...)

> type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

error. I have tried some other ways to convert the string into a JsonArray or to loop through the string, but without success.

What I'm doing wrong??

Edit: 
The data in jsonString:

```
{"lights":{"1":{"state":{"on":false,"bri":254,"hue":4444,"sat":254,"xy":[0.0,0.0],"ct":0,"alert":"none","effect":"none","colormode":"hs","reachable":true},"type":"Extended color light","name":"Hue Lamp 1","modelid":"LCT001","swversion":"65003148","uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:00:d4:12:08-0a","pointsymbol":{"1":"none","2":"none","3":"none","4":"none","5":"none","6":"none","7":"none","8":"none"}},"2":{"state":{"on":false,"bri":254,"hue":23536,"sat":144,"xy":[0.346,0.3568],"ct":201,"alert":"none","effect":"none","colormode":"hs","reachable":true},"type":"Extended color light","name":"Hue Lamp 2","modelid":"LCT001","swversion":"65003148","uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:00:d4:12:08-0b","pointsymbol":{"1":"none","2":"none","3":"none","4":"none","5":"none","6":"none","7":"none","8":"none"}},"3":{"state":{"on":true,"bri":254,"hue":65136,"sat":254,"xy":[0.346,0.3568],"ct":201,"alert":"none","effect":"none","colormode":"hs","reachable":true},"type":"Extended color light","name":"Hue Lamp 3","modelid":"LCT001","swversion":"65003148","uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:00:d4:12:08-0c","pointsymbol":{"1":"none","2":"none","3":"none","4":"none","5":"none","6":"none","7":"none","8":"none"}}},"schedules":{"1":{"time":"2012-10-29T12:00:00","description":"","name":"schedule","command":{"body":{"scene":null,"on":true,"xy":null,"bri":null,"transitiontime":null},"address":"/api/newdeveloper/groups/0/action","method":"PUT"}}},"config":{"portalservices":false,"gateway":"192.168.2.1","mac":"00:00:88:00:bb:ee","swversion":"01005215","linkbutton":false,"ipaddress":"192.168.178.31:5510","proxyport":0,"swupdate":{"text":"","notify":false,"updatestate":0,"url":""},"netmask":"255.255.255.0","name":"Philips hue","dhcp":true,"proxyaddress":"","whitelist":{"newdeveloper":{"name":"test user","last use date":"2016-04-06T16:51:26","create date":"2012-10-29T12:00:00"}},"UTC":"2012-10-29T12:05:00"},"groups":{"1":{"name":"Group 1","action":{"on":true,"bri":254,"hue":33536,"sat":144,"xy":[0.346,0.3568],"ct":201,"alert":null,"effect":"none","colormode":"xy","reachable":null},"lights":["1","2"]}},"scenes":{}}
```

Comment: can you show what you are trying to parsing?

Comment: `lights ` is not a type jsonarray post your json string

Comment: lights is a JSONObject and not an array

Comment: Added the jsonString data. Lights is a JSONArray.

Comment: here lights is jsonobject you can't parse it to jsonarray

Comment: Are there other ways to loop to the data to get al the "lights" ?

Comment: @NVO `lights` is a type jsonObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `"lights"` is not a `JSONArray` but a `JSONObject`. So to retrieve the contents of `"lights"` you need to iterate through all the objects of `"lights"` using the `keys()` method.

Replace the code from your `try` block with the following code to iterate through all the objects inside `"lights"`.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
 JSONObject lights = jsonObject.getJSONObject("lights");
 Iterator<String> keyIterator = lights.keys();

 while (keys.hasNext()) {
     String key = keyIterator.next();
     JSONObject l = lights.getJSONObject(key);

     String name = l.getString("name");
     String bri = l.getString("bri");
     String hue = l.getString("hue");
     String sat = l.getString("sat");
     String status = l.getString("on");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

the key "lights" maps to a `JSONObject` and you are converting it to a `JSONArray` hence the exception.Change the line

```
lights = jsonObject.getJSONArray("lights");
```

to

```
JSONObject lights = jsonObject.getJSONObject("lights");
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to parse the JSON objects with each different key and value, using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581299/how-to-parse-the-json-objects-with-each-different-key-and-value-using-java)
visit this link.. and there you can access different key and values with that. so you don't have to worry about key. and you are having key like "1" and "2" and so on.  so just iterate through **lights** object and you will get your answer. if you have any problem with that feel free to ask.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("<jsonString>");
Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();

while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + json.get(key));
}
```

from this you will get key and after that you have to just get values of that object.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you:

```
String jsonString = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(BASE_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

if (jsonString != null) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);


        for (int 1 = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            JSONObject l = jsonObject.getJSONObject("lights").getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));

            String name = l.getString("name");
            String bri = l.getString("bri");
            String hue = l.getString("hue");
            String sat = l.getString("sat");
            String status = l.getString("on");
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Cannot get data from the url");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `JSONObject` every key maps to a `JSONObject` not to a `JSONArray`. So you have to read like this from your `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject lights = jsonObject.getJSONObject("lights");

JSONObject schedules = jsonObject.getJSONObject("schedules");

JSONObject config = jsonObject.getJSONObject("config");

JSONObject groups = jsonObject.getJSONObject("groups");

JSONObject scenes = jsonObject.getJSONObject("scenes");
```

Hope it will help for you.